# Vue 3 defineModel not updating child component with v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input component using new defineModel()

```
<template>
  <textarea
    v-model="model"
    required
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineModel } from 'vue'

const model = defineModel()
</script>
```

then in paren component:

```
 <article-comment-input v-model="msg"></article-comment-input>
const msg = ref('')
```

I also have a add a comment function:

```
async function addComments() {
  const response = await commentsStore.addComment(msg.value, id)
  msg.value = ''
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    makeAToast('Something went wrong', 'warning')
  }
  makeAToast('Added', 'success')
}
```

and the problem is that

```
 msg.value = ''
```

doesnt reset the value of input after submitting comment. Why it doesnt reset- two way data binding doesnt work using model?

Comment: works fine https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/BXLl7RSaQ69lbTioR5A4iHg6EuabILbxA5+lEpV/p3dmIYUUU7J7ozHs5498Oumme488DlPbGZk45gF55ulULJutHHswAwUrGWF0TWLkBr10K2um+/+NKaClKJLoTKtrGO1LdmCTo+iaIzdJA43oDYWDuqmSh1gxViSkdTuotY5VAvB8ajg8TJZmzjga++cVuwqq2S2DQTUjiLBly+AjpM4MJCdxANpPuHOop1CltON1QrnPJCg4HSjrMA8NU6iXcHnrEMIS6tKf953PWc8TI797B2y7R/9jd1TT/Bng2bMDgTvMZeaElyAV6+PsMf/HsR5fYXsf0AcT1eePAbajVc52h7wOrd3XSRSlW92tXeg7HEoMkrMtuMLjhFRVOdG/7E7m866c0K1+IrHeGlRTqNz6Do1kAaFQYb0FTy0DXx4aSCniiI9CQnLc7uXQyEVPJDUrx3st6zDFkPmaDxYNt5+AcAz9+0=

Comment: you forgot `else` for the success toast

Comment: are you sure `msg.value = ''` is executed and `addComment` doesn't throw an error?

Comment: thanks sir for answer; this code comes from vue docs which i used to implement this input, but in my whole component it doesnt reset and nothing is in console.

Comment: do any of the `makeToast` execute? what if you remove `const response = await commentsStore.addComment(msg.value, id)` - perhaps `commentsStore.addComment` returns a Promise that is never settled

Comment: is addComments in the parent component? how is it called? does the network request complete?  if you add a console.log after does the console.log execute?  You've not provided enough code to fully reproduce so it's unlikely we can spot where the error is until you do.

Comment: SUGGESTION: OP, I don't know what errors you see in console (that would help us), but I would suggest that you'd want to set a default value in `defineModel`, like so: `const model = defineModel({default: ''})`.